# Running tar in a bash script returns "Output with bankrupt according to previous errors"

Tags: linux, bash, centos, backup

Please don't say me that there is duplicate post (i know that it is a common problem) but i would to knows my errors and learn from it

The question is why this script is not working for me? I would like to find what i made wrong

OS Centos 6

**Problem** : i need to tar and send some files located in this dir
`/home/teamportal/data/filestorage/www/_cron_db_bak`

**what i have done looking online and glueing**

```
#!/bin/bash
day=$(date +%F)
Folder="/home/teamportal/data/filestorage/www/_cron_db_bak"
File="/root/backup/$day.tar"
tar cvf $File $Folder
cat /home/mailmessage.txt |mutt -a $File -s "BACKUP Database" -- mail1@gmail.com mail2@somedomain.com mail3@gmail.com
find $File* -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;
```

**ERROR**

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/teamportal/data/filestorage/www/_cron_db_bak\r\r: stat failed: No such file or directory
tar: Output with bankrupt according to previous errors
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

BTW the mail is sent but the file is corrupted and looking into directory i notice that

```
ls /root/backup
^M^M    2015-02-25^M.tar^M     2015-02-25^M.tar.gz^M
```

Thanks to anyone let me understand what i did wrong .

Cheers

EDIT :
Thanks for let me understand the problem (windows in this case)

so i m sharing to others the script i made in case they ll need

http://pastebin.com/uabfLjQW

cheers

Comment: try running `dos2unix yourscript.sh`, then run it again and report errors if any

Comment: perfect guido , i didn't know about the windows problem in doing scripts & sorry for let you editing my post and loosing so much time . i m going to share my script to other people in case they need

Comment: @AndreaNostro you welcome; there is no point in linking external resource from this site (as link may go broken); better to post (paste) your code while creating your own answer to the question (while explaining what was the problem about end of lines: so that your post could really be useful for others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing end of line for windows and unix in your script

If you look at it using `od -x myScript.sh`, you'll see a mix of characters 0a and 0d for end of line.

Make sure you fix it correctly (e.g. using [vi](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/) ) and your script should work